# Is this Date a valid one in Java?

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-parsing

Is this `00/00/00` a valid Date which is in `MM/dd/yy` format in Java?

I have tried this below sample code to see if the `00/00/00` is a valid one in Java. But, the date which is getting parsed is `SUN Nov 30 00:00:00 IST 2`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy").parse("00/00/00"));

}
```

If not, how do I parse the Date string `"00/00/00"` in the format `MM/dd/yy` in Java?

The thing is I need to read the string `00/00/00`, which is obtained in a text file. In this process, I am getting SUN Nov 30 00:00:00 IST 2 as output when I parsed that string using `parse()` method of `SimpleDateFormat`. But, I am expecting 0th Year, 0thDay, 0thMonth as output. Do you think this is possible?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `Run as --> Java Application` thats all you need to do.

Comment: Why do you need to parse `00/00/00` to a `Date`? And what would be month zero and day zero? I'm failing to see the point here...

Comment: 0/0/0 is one month and one day before 1/1/0 so Nov 30 seems correct.

Comment: try with `simpleDateFormat.setLenient(false);`. By default, `SimpleDateFormat` tries its very best to be helpful.  Sometimes it's *too* helpful, and happily parses gibberish dates like that

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/286538). `00/00/00` is not really a valid date. Why are you trying to parse it? Why not just detect that it is equal to `00/00/00` as a string and then use a predetermined value or behavior instead? Please explain the context of the question.

Comment: No it’s not a valid date. There is no year 0, no 0th month and no 0th day in a month. `SimpleDateFormat` in lenient mode (see @MrSpoon’s comment) is lenient enough to parse it anyway.

Comment: @Henry, to explain a little more fully, 0/0/0 is parsed as 1 year 1 month 1 day before 1/1/1 AD, where the year before year 1 is year 1 BC, so year 2 (BC) seems correct too (if correctness makes sense here).

Comment: DilipKumarC, do you know what result you want? As I said, there is no such date in the calendar, so there is no way to obtain a date that will print back as 00/00/00.

Comment: Thank you every one. The thing is I need to read the string 00/00/00 which is obtained in a text file. In this process, I am getting SUN Nov 30 00:00:00 IST 2 as output when I parsed that string using parse() method of SimpleDateFormat. But, I am expecting 0th Year, 0thDay, 0thMonth as output. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: As the comments above have already said, that's not possible. The best you can do is check if the `String` is `00/00/00` and handle it separately - or try to parse with the `setLenient(false)` option and catch the exception.

Comment: Third, but poorer, option, check if resulting date equals SUN Nov 30 00:00:00 IST 2 and handle this case specially. Note that the 2 in the end refers to year 2 *before* the common era (BCE).

Comment: As an aside, consider using the modern `DateTimeFormatter` in preference to the outdated `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: As to why someone would be generating/parsing the string `"00/00/00"`, it *might* be a misguided attempt to represent a ‘null’-type of value, an unknown date.

Comment: Why the down-votes? This seems like a legitimate question to me. A quick check did not find any duplicate questions about a date-only string value of `00/00/00`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hugo already said it:

> The best you can do is check if the `String` is `00/00/00` and handle it
>   separately - or try to parse with the `setLenient(false)` option and
>   catch the exception.

What I want to do here is show you how you can skip the outdated (and quite often troublesome) `SimpleDateFormat` class and follow the suggestion using the modern Java date and time API.

My preferred solution is checking the date string explicitly:

```
    if (dateFromFile.equals("00/00/00")) {
        System.out.println("0000-00-00");
    } else {
        System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(dateFromFile, 
                                           DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yy")));
    }
```

I am assuming your string is in a `String dateFromFile`.

The other option is you try to parse the string and catch the exception (the modern `DateTimeFormatter` isn’t lenient per default):

```
    try {
        System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(dateFromFile, 
                   DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yy")));
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
        System.out.println("0000-00-00");
    }
```

One potential advantage is it will also catch cases where the string contains zeroes for unknown fields but isn’t literally equal to `00/00/00` — for example `07/00/17` or `0/0/0`.

Third and poorest option, parse leniently and compare to the date that comes out of `00/00/00`:

```
    DateTimeFormatter parseFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yy")
            .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.LENIENT);
    LocalDate unknownDateParsed = LocalDate.of(1999, Month.NOVEMBER, 30);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateFromFile, parseFormatter);
    if (date.equals(unknownDateParsed)) {
        System.out.println("0000-00-00");
    } else {
        System.out.println(date);
    }
```

`DateTimeFormatter` assumes 2000–2099 when you give it a two-digit year, so `00/00/00` becomes November 30, 1999 because it is 1 month 1 day before 01/01/2000.

One issue with the last approach is poorer validation: it will let other incorrect dates like for example `05/35/17` or `13/32/45` pass without notice.

Answer (score 1):

## Treat such input as an error

As others have said, there is no month zero nor day-of-month zero in modern Western chronology.

Therefore, I would treat such input as an error condition, and reject the input.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter. ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( Locale.US ) ;
…

if( input.equals( "00/00/00" ) ) { 
    … // handle error 
} else {
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ; 
}
```

You should ask the source of the data if this is an error or a special value. Perhaps it is meant to be a stand-in for a “null”-type of value, an unknown date. If so, I would suggest an alternative. For example, the word “unknown” or a designated date value. One possible such value, assuming your known values are more recent, might be the [common epoch reference date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) of 1970-01-01. For date-time, use the constant `Instant.EPOCH` value, 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.